# How to add a color bar in the scatterplot using axis plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, colorbar

I am trying to plot a scatter plot between price and volume. These quantities also varies across various hours of the day. Therefore. I also want to show hour as a color bar. However, I am unable to add a color bar in my axis plot.

```
fig,(ax2,ax3) = plt.subplots(2,1, figsize = (36,24))
ax2.scatter(df3_sell['volume'],df3_sell['price'],c = df3_sell['hour'],cmap='jet')
ax2.set_xlabel('Volume [MW]', fontsize=12, color='black')
ax2.set_ylabel('Price [Euro]', fontsize=12, color='black')
ax2.grid(True)

ax3.scatter(df3_buy['volume'],df3_buy['price'],c = df3_buy['hour'],cmap='viridis')
ax3.set_xlabel('Volume [MW]', fontsize=12, color='black')
ax3.set_ylabel('Price [Euro]', fontsize=12, color='black')
ax3.grid(True)
```

I am also sharing my output here.
[image]

It gives me an error (AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'colorbar'), when I try to add a color bar using ax2.colorbar().

I also tried below.

```
c1 = ax2.scatter(df3_sell['volume'],df3_sell['price'],c = df3_sell['hour'],cmap='jet')
ax2.set_xlabel('Volume', fontsize=f1, color='black')
ax2.set_ylabel('Price', fontsize=f1, color='black')
ax2.grid(True)
cbar = fig.colorbar(c1)

c2 = ax3.scatter(df3_buy['volume'],df3_buy['price'],c = df3_buy['hour'],cmap='viridis')
ax3.set_xlabel('Volume', fontsize=f1, color='black')
ax3.set_ylabel('Price', fontsize=f1, color='black')
ax3.grid(True)
cbar = fig.colorbar(c2)
```

However, it messed up the color bars.
[image]

Any suggestions will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: You have not included the code that adds the colorbar.  Note that colorbar is a figure method

Comment: Hi @JodyKlymak
Correct, it is not there. I tried to did it with ax2.colorbar(). But it is not an attribute to axis.
I am trying to plot 2x2 plots and I am trying to add colorbar for these bottom two.

Comment: @JodyKlymak
Edited my questing with code and output.

Comment: What do you mean by “messed up”.  Suggest you read the tutorial on colorbar placement.  https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/colorbar_placement.html

Comment: Thanks @JodyKlymak for sharing this. It helped. Instead of hardcoding axis like ax02, I moved to ax[i,j] and it worked.

Comment: `fig.colorbar(c1, ax=ax2)` might also help

Comment: Hi @JohanC
I had tried it but did not work.